# Are all mathematical laws tautologies?

Tags: logic, soft-question, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm reading a book by Tarski and he says:
"Every scientific theory is a system of sentences which are accepted as true and which may be called laws"
then after some pages he gives somme laws:

for any p and q:

1) if p, then p

2) if p, then q or p

3) if p and q, then p

etc

All of these are tautologies, but are "laws" in general tautologies? Could I say law = tautology? When I read, for example, Leibniz's law, symmetry law, associative law etc should I see them all as tautologies?

Comment: The term "law" is informal, so it may denote an axiom, or a property, postulate,  theorem, or even an informal rule or pattern which cannot be formulated formally.

Comment: The word "accepted" already indicates that the sentences are not necessarily tautologies. A tautology needs no acceptance.

Comment: @coffeemath Really? It looks like a tautology to me.

Comment: @coffeemath Oh, I see. I have removed my comment. And will remove this comment as well later.

Answer (score 3):

NO.

[Tautologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)#Definition_and_examples) are formulas that are universally valid, i.e. true in every interpretation.

Mathematical axioms and theorems are not so.

Consider e.g. the *arithmetical* theorem: $\forall n (n \ge 0)$. This "law" is true for natural numbers, but it is false for integers, rationals, etc.

Thus, it cannot be true in every interpretation.

The same for the [Associative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property):

> Associative operations are abundant in mathematics; in fact, many algebraic structures (such as semigroups and categories) explicitly require their binary operations to be associative.
>
> However, many important and interesting operations are non-associative; some examples include subtraction, exponentiation, and the vector cross product.

---

> "Every scientific theory is a system of sentences which are accepted as true and which may be called laws."

We have *axioms*, i.e. sentences assumed as true: they are the starting points of the theory.

And we have *theorems*, i.e. sentences deduced from axioms by way of valid arguments.

We may call axioms and theorems: "the laws of the theory".

Comment: So is something like Modus Ponen an assumption/axiom/law, or is it a theorem because you can prove $[(p \implies q) \wedge p] \implies q$ is a tautology?

Comment: @Blue - usually, we d not consider a logical calculus as a "scientific theory".

Comment: Having said that, we have calculus with rules only (Natural deduction) and calculus (aka: proof systems) with axioms and rules (so-called Hilbert-style). In the last case, we have some tautologies assumed as basic (axioms) and we use rules of inference to derive all tautologies from the basic ones (Completeness of the calculus).

Comment: So would modus ponens be a "rule"? Also, if you have no axioms whatsoever, isn't that system "boring" because there's nothing you can do? Or is that the setting you just study logic itself in?